# Is it possible to make a virtual function that would return a proper unique_ptr of derived type?

Tags: c++, templates, covariance

I want to make function `clone()` actually overridable, as I need it to be polymorphic in my application.

```
class Component
{
    virtual Component *cloneImpl() const = 0;

public:
    std::unique_ptr<Component> clone() const
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<Component>(this->cloneImpl());
    }
};
```

As of right now, what I managed to do was to hide the `clone()` function inside some derived components, but that lead to severe runtime issues. Is it somehow possible to make it work in a way that would allow me to do this? :

```
class DerivedComponent : public Component
{
    DerivedComponent* cloneImpl() const
    {
        return new DerivedComponent();
    }

public:
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedComponent> clone() const override
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<DerivedComponent>(this->cloneImpl());
    }
};
```

I was thinking of using templates, but unfortunately that didn't lead me anywhere.

I want it to be truly polymorphic, not just hiding the base class' `clone()` method.

I fear what I want to do is impossible, but I decided that it's worth asking here just to make sure I don't waste more time thinking about it.

Comment: What do you mean by a "proper" `unique_ptr`? With polymorphism, the override needs the same return type as the base class, so why not have your `DerivedComponent` `clone()` return a `std::unique_ptr<Component>` (which is *actually* a `std::unique_ptr<DerivedComponent>`)?

Comment: The only thing i can think of is CRTP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Polymorphic_copy_construction

Comment: @AdrianMole No, the must not be the same, tr must only be covariant, which mean that for raw pointer you can return a more specialised type.

Comment: Yes--covariant return is what allows `DerivedComponent::clomeImpl` return a `DerivedComponent *`, even though it overrides `Component::cloneImpl`, which returns a `Component *`. But `unique_ptr<Derived>` isn't derived from `unique_ptr<Base>`, even though `Derived` is derived from `Base`.

Comment: @AdrianMole that could work, but if I'm not mistaken, it would require additional casting if I wanted to use methods specific to derived component, right?

Comment: @gerum Sorry - My bad. But that doesn't work for STL types with different template classes, even if one is derived from the other.

Comment: IIRC, polymorphism works well with smart pointers.

Comment: OK - I missed your point about methods *specific* to the derived classes.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for trying though, I think I'll just either have to do some weird casting, or just be careful and make the `clone()` return a raw pointer

Comment: If your intent is to be able to call member functions (or access members) of `DerivedComponent` that are not inherited from `Component`, then - usually - you're introducing a code smell anyway.   The only way that works is for code *using* the component to either *know* or *assume* that the object is a (smart pointer managing) a `DerivedComponent`  (e.g. a runtime check using `dynamic_cast`, assume it does without checking and face undefined behaviour if it doesn't). Consider redesigning so `Component` provides the required interface (e.g. overrideable virtuals).

Answer (score 1):

With C++20, I would define an implicit CRTP using deduced this:

```
#include <comcepts>

struct Component
{
    virtual ~Component() = 0; //must be virtual
    virtual unique_ptr<Component> dynamic_clone() const = 0;
    auto static_clone(this auto const& self) {
         return std::make_unique 
                <std::remove_cvref_t
                <decltype(self)>>(self);
    }
    auto clone(this auto const& self) {
         using  self_t =         
                std::remove_cvref_t
                <decltype(self)>>;

         return std::unique_ptr<self_t>
                {dynamic_cast<self_t>
                (self.dynamic_clon()
                .release())};
    }
};

template<std::derived_from<Component> derived>
struct Concrete : derived {
     using derived::derived;
     ~Concrete() override = default;
     unique_ptr<Component> dynamic_clone() const override
     { return {this->static_clone()}; };
};

auto derived_ptr = std::make_unique<Concrete<DerivedComponent>>();
```

The `static_clone` member acts on the static type of its object, while rhe `dynamic_clone` member creates a new copy based on dynamic type of its object. Because the entire hierarchy is abstract by `dynamic_clone`, only `Concrete` instances can be created.

**Edit:**

covariant `clone` is added with static type of current instance and dynamic type of infered pointer. `clone` and `static_clone` could be implemented as `static`functions or free none-member templates as well, but this snippet is just a hasty hack.

Comment: This always returns `unique_ptr<Component>` while OP wants to *return a proper unique_ptr of derived type*

Comment: No. The actual infered pointer is always an instance of `Concrete`. If `dynamic_clone` is called, the return value is `unique_ptr<Component>` but the runtime type is erased amd embedded in vtable. If the `static_clone` is used, the static type is `unique_ptr<Concrete<Component>>`,  and the infered pointer is a pointer to exact type of argument. You either know the exact static type or use some form of RTTI. with normal pointers there's a covariant retun type available, but it is not available for smart pointers.

Comment: Your solution injects `static_clone` in the derived class, which is fine and dandy, but this is not what OP is asking for (and you don't really need fancy c++23 stuff for it anyway). The problem is that you need to use different versions of `clone` depending on whether you have a base pointer or a derived pointer, and neither is right if you have a concrete class in the middle of a hierarchy.

Comment: Preventing the middle concrete class needs another trick. A dummy input of a type befriended to `Concrete` so nobody can actually override `dynamic_clone`. For now, we just keep it simple by promising not to override the function.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Just guessing at what you are after. Its not really clear what you want in the end..

```
template <typename T>
class Component {
    virtual T *cloneImpl() const = 0;

  public:
    virtual ~Component() = default;
    std::unique_ptr<T> clone() const {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(this->cloneImpl());
    }
};

class DerivedComponent : public Component<DerivedComponent> {
  private:
    DerivedComponent* cloneImpl() const {
        return new DerivedComponent();
    }
  public:
    ~DerivedComponent() = default;
};
```

Comment: this might be a different type of problem, but while this compiles, it fails at runtime (with no error, gdb just quits with error code 139 before even the first line of `main()` is executed) for some components (one of these holds a map of unique_otrs to different component type), same as what I previously experienced with shadowing of clone()

Comment: I think for the virtual functions to work as intended, you would need a separate non-template base class

Comment: @aallfik11 Not sure what you are talking about. It compiles and works just fine for me with no errors. My usage looks like this. `DerivedComponent d; auto c = d.clone();` What was your usage which caused a runtime error for you?

Comment: Yeah it's my usage that seems to be wrong, but not necessarily because of your implementation. I've made a new post about it, since it happends even in a different scenario

Comment: @Davidvanrijn I am afraid, you are wrong. I have used patterns similar to this countless times in the last decade and this is perfectly legal C++ code.

Comment: I was more thinking of a usage perspective, where you want to have an abstract (smart) pointer, which can hold any object Derived from `Component`.  Not trying to criticise, just add some info :)

Comment: I've resolved my runtime problem, but unfortunately, while I like how it works It's not suited for my use case. I've got an entity class storing components, as such the container's storage type is the base "Component" class. With this solution, it doesn't work as it requires a class argument to pass into the template.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably write the code something along this general line:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Component
{
    virtual Component *cloneImpl() const = 0;
public:
    virtual void test() const = 0;
    
    template <class T> friend std::unique_ptr<T> clone(T const &cmp) {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(cmp.cloneImpl());
    }

    template <class T> friend std::unique_ptr<T> clone(std::unique_ptr<T> const &cmp) {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(cmp->cloneImpl());
    }
};

class Derived : public Component
{
    Derived* cloneImpl() const override
    {
        return new Derived();
    }
    template <class T> friend std::unique_ptr<T> clone(std::unique_ptr<T> const &);
    template <class T> friend std::unique_ptr<T> clone(T const &);
public:

    virtual void test() const { std::cout << "Derived component\n"; }
};

class D2 : public Component {
    D2 *cloneImpl() const override {
        return new D2();
    }
    template <class T> friend std::unique_ptr<T> clone(std::unique_ptr<T> const &);
    template <class T> friend std::unique_ptr<T> clone(T const &);
public:
    virtual void test() const { std::cout << "D2\n"; }

    virtual void test2() const { std::cout << "D2 unique item\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    D2 d2;

    // test cloning a derived object:
    auto ret1 = clone(d);
    ret1->test();

    // make sure clone of derived gives a unique_ptr<derived>
    auto ret2 = clone(d2);
    ret2->test();
    ret2->test2();

    // test cloning when we start with a unique_ptr<T>
    auto ret3 = clone(ret2);
    ret3->test2();
}
```

I should probably point out a few things here that may not immediately be obvious:

- `clone` is a friend of the classes. Since `friend`ship isn't inherited, each derived class has to re-declare `clone` as being its friend.
- Despite its definition being inside of `Component`'s class definition, `clone` isn't a member function--since it's a `friend`, it can't be a member, so it's "injected" into the surrounding namespace (the global namespace, in this case).
- Even though it's a global function, there's no *declaration* of `clone` in the global namespace. This means `clone` can only be found via argument dependent lookup. For example, if we added some unrelated class:

  ```cpp
  class Unrelated {
      Unrelated *cloneImpl() { return new Unrelated; }
  };

  // ...
  Unrelated u;
  auto ret3 = clone(u);
  ```

  ...the code won't compile (even though `Unrelated`) provides the `cloneImpl` that `clone` needs, so under other circumstances, it could work). If you wanted this to work, I'm pretty sure adding the `friend` declaration to `Unrelated` would let it work though.
- I've added another derived class that defines another member function that's not defined in the base class, so we can show that when we clone a derived object, we get an actual `unique_ptr<Derived>` that can be used to invoke a Derived-specific function without any casting or other conversion.
- Cloning usually means you're dealing with a fair number of things via pointers (or in this case, `unique_ptr`s)--so I've included overloads to take the input as either an object or a `unique_ptr` (both return a `unique_ptr` to the clone).

Comment: I don't see anything that would prevent `clone` from being a member.

Comment: @n.m.: I tend to look at it from the opposite direction: is there a specific reason `clone` should be a member? Would we gain anything from its being a member? The only gain I see is not needing `friend` declarations in the derived classes, but I'm not sure I find that particularly convincing, though it might be if you expected to have a *lot* of derived classes.

Comment: "is there a specific reason clone should be a member?" Yes: to reduce boilerplate (many `friend` declarations) sounds like a good enough reason.

Comment: As I said, I don't find that particularly convincing unless I'm pretty sure there are going to be a lot of derived classes.

Comment: I'd actually need clone to be a member because I have a container of "Component" base class in my other class, which is supposed to call "clone" in some cases and should return a pointer of a derived class

Comment: the problem is that I want clone to simply return a proper derived unique_ptr even when called on a pointer to base "Component', while your solution unfortunately takes an argument, which wouldn't work in my implementation

Comment: @aallfik11: Given that you apparently have requirement far beyond what's stated in the question, you should edit the question to explain those requirements (or ask a new question that contains the actual requirements you want to meet).